# ASP.NET Core MVC is throwing in app service "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I have created an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application. It's working fine locally. But once deployed to the app service I am getting the following error.

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

I have my `program.cs` configured with

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

After deploying the code to the app service If I access with `https:azurewebsites.net/home/index`, it throws that error. Please suggest how to fix this.

Comment: First of all, the URL that you're providing is obviously incomplete -- I imagine that it's on purpose due to privacy concerns. In the future I would advise doing something like: `https://{ourAppServiceName}.azurewebsites.net/Home/Index` to make it clear that the URL you're attempting to access isn't causing the issue.
Secondly, you're going to need to provide more details regarding your implementation, error logs from `Azure AppService`, etc. in order to have the best chance of getting help.

Comment: Thanks for the response !as pe rapp insights it was just showing " localhost
GET /" 403 error .

Comment: can you provide deployment logs in app service.

Comment: Are you deploying to windows or Linux app service? please share complete code which you are tried.

Comment: Deploying to windows .From the index.cshtml I'm calling home controller . I have the following code in program.cs 
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

Answer (score 1):

I tried a simple ASP.NET Core 6 MVC, and it was successfully deployed to the Azure App Service.

If you define routes in your controller and add a web.config file to your root directory, ensure that your paths and routes are correct.

I defined incorrect routes in my controller, and I also faced issue.

**Program.cs**

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
       app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.Run();
```

**.csproj**

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**Local Output**:
[image]

I was able see the output in browser after deployment.

**Azure App Service Output**:
[image]

[image]